# How I can avoid duplicate query if I am validating input in my laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have the following controller:

```
function myRequest(Request $request)
{
  $validator = Valiodator($request->all(),[
     'user_id'=>"required|integer|min:1|exists:users,id"
     // Rest of validation rules here
  ]);

  if($validator->fails(){
     // Handle error here and respond accorditly
  }
  
  $user = User::find($request->get('user_id'));
  // Process user further via a model or a service class
  
}
```

But this results querying the database twice. Can I do input validation and query the db once without losing any convenience of using the validator?

Comment: While yes, it would query the database against the `users` table twice, it's two separate queries; the 1st is an `exists` query, while the 2nd runs a `SELECT *` against the single supplied `user_id`. I don't think there would be a way to take the result of the query run by the `Validator` (sidenote, you have a typo `Valiodator`) and convert that to an equivalent result that `User::find()` returns. You could short circuit your Validation's query by checking `if (!User::find($request->input('user_id')) { return ... }` (or similar), which would eliminate 1 query, but I think you still need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go with a custom validation rules as a Closure, something like:

```php
$user = new User;
$validator = Valiodator($request->all(),[
    'user_id' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        'min:1',
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) use (&$user) {
            $user = User::find($value);
            // rest of validation logic
        }
    ],
]);
```